# Are there any cons to having multiple regex validation expression to validate a string?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, webforms, expression

I am trying to create a full validation expression to validate matrices that people send me using a multiline textbox. In order to satisfy this I have to compensate to allow different formats and lauguage types of matrices produced by different softwares. The only way I can validate different languages is to use separate each language's validation with `^...$ | ^...$ | ^...$ |` etc...

Each of these validation expressions are quite complex and long. Are there any cons in doing so? My main concern is whether or not my multiple validations will affect my site's performance and speed when a user submits their matrices.

Can anyone confirm whether or not there are flaws or cons in using complex, long multiple validation expressions for large strings of data?

Comment: I created an answer, but i'll elaborate more on the performance issues. Just give me a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not Efficient

The way you are describing your regex, makes it sound very expensive. If the regex does not find a match, it will move on to the next `or` statement. And start back at the beginning of the string. This can be a big performance hit for a large string. If your expression uses any `*`or`+` notation, then it runs the risk of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). This affect will be multiplied by however many "or" statements it'll have to go through before it finds a match. Imagine if it **never** finds a match. Then your poor user ends up waiting a very long time, just to get an invalid notice.

### Error Handling

Think of what kind of feedback you are going to give the user once it fails. Currently, the only feedback you can give them is "Validation Failed". The user will be wondering may think that the format is wrong, when all reality you don't support the language. This can be confusing for the user. Also, as mentioned above, depending on the size of the matrix, your user could be waiting a LONG time to get a response. So you want to make sure that response is as constructive as possible.

### Alternative Solution

Instruct your users to declare the language they are using. This could be done via radio box or something of that nature. If you want to only use the text box, instruct the users to write their language in the first line. And then instruct them to start the matrix on the second line.

That way you do a quick check to see if the language is supported. If not, spit out an error to the user. If it is, then you'll know exactly what regex to run on the matrix. Since you'll only have 1 regex to run, you won't have as big of a performance hit.

Comment: @shockwave123 That is a great explanation! I'm glad that I asked this and mentioned that these matrices could be very large! 

So if I create a simple radio box with each language listed, I would have to apply the validation expression based on which radio they selected. The problem with that is that I have absolutely no clue how to write that function or what language to use to do so. Do you think you can slowly guide me through this process? I will open up a new question if you confirm that you're able to help me? :) Thanks again for that detailed explanation it makes perfect sense now!

Comment: ahh... i'm not too familiar with asp.net so i won't be much help. But glad you liked my response! Wish i could help you out more.

Comment: Great help regardless! Thanks again for clearing that up for me. Would you happen to know which language can accomplish this? I'm hoping javascript since that is the only language I know how to incorporate into my web from :S

Comment: @shoackawave123 Im just confused as to how/where I would write separate validation expressions to satisfy the function you explained.

Comment: Where do you do the validation? Do you already do it with javascript?

Comment: Right now I express the validation in ASP. Im not sure if I can set separate validation using ASP. The only way I knew was what I asked in my question.